# Why was "cart price rule based on payment method" removed from Magento 2.1.8?

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

When Magento 2.0 came out, the well-known feature from Magento 1 - to add the payment method as a condition for a cart price rule - was not implemented.

Magento 2.1 added this feature. Lately we updated a system to 2.1.9 and noticed that the feature was missing again. It is still present in version 2.1.7 and I assume it has been removed in version 2.1.8.

On Github, I think this is the commit that removed the feature:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb65d05d41f30cd6a10fdfffb10b1dd8f42d3a77#diff-6af1fa68376d90ae611de38779431624

Interesting enough, we have cart rules in place that were created with "payment method" as a condition and they are still working.

It would be nice if anyone could answer the question if I am missing something here, or if it's safe to write a small plugin for the function `loadAttributeOptions()` and simply add the payment method again.

Comment: i am looking for this answer too

Answer (score 1):

There is this module that will do that for you

https://github.com/gcampedelli/Payment-Method-Discount---Magento2

Answer (score 0):

It's an acceptable decision to remove payment method as condition for cart price rule. Since logically, you would select payment method after applying coupon.
I have been trying to add plugin to show payment method option on condition, but the coupons cannot be applied no matter what.
Please follow the issue reported on Github https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24206

Comment: There are shopping cart price rules that will be applied without a coupon code. For example: 2% discount (Skonto) if you pay upfront … That's very common in the D-A-CH region.